# C++ считывание из файла wchar_t

Tags: c++, файлы, строки

Здравствуйте.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    wstring test;
    wchar_t c;

    fstream fin;
    fin.open("test_file");

}
```

В test_file находится строка, состоящая из символов как русского, так и английского алфавитов. Каким образом можно посимвольно считать всю строку, чтобы на каждой итерации в переменной "с" хранился один символ? Задача состоит в том, чтобы из файла считать строку, к примеру "ТестTest" и чтобы потом команда `test.length()` вернула не 12, а 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wchar_t` работает с `UCS-2` (вариантом UTF-16, строго 2 байта на символ). Текст же, судя по `test.length()`, закодирован в UTF-8 (1 байт на латиницу, 2-3 байта на прочее).

Для преобразования между кодировками необходимо использовать один из двух способов:

1. Конвертирующие классы, так называемые *фасеты*. Для наших целей потребуется [`codecvt_utf8`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_utf8/) (доступен, начиная с C++11):

   ```
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>

   int main()
   {
       std::wstring test;

       std::fstream fin;
       fin.open("test_file");

       std::locale loc(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>);
       ofs.imbue(loc);

       // Дальнейшие операции чтения будут работать уже с корректно 
       // преобразованным потоком `wchar_t`
   }
   ```
2. Стандартные функции Windows API, а именно [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx):

   ```
   // Сначала считываем строку как последовательность `char`. Затем преобразуем
   // считанную строку с помощью этой функции:
   std::wstring decode(const char* src)
   {
       std::vector<wchar_t> buffer;
       buffer.resize(MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, src, -1, 0, 0));
       MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, src, -1, &buffer[0], buffer.size());
       return &buffer[0];
   }
   ```

**Важное замечание:** UCS-2 является подмножеством UTF-16, не поддерживающим суррогатные пары. Из-за этого он включает в себя далеко не все символы Unicode. Это необходимо учесть при работе с азиатскими и всякими редкими писменностями.